# AWS S3 CloudFormation Read-Only Permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create two users and grant user1 read-only permission to the s3 bucket, I also need to grant user2 Read and Write access. Here is what I have done so far

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"


Resources:
  s3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private

  User1:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User

  User2:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User

  User1Key:
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      UserName: !Ref 'User1'

  User2Key:
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      UserName: !Ref 'User2'
Outputs:
  AccessKey:
    Value: !Ref 'User1Key'
    Description: AWSAccessKeyId of User 1
  SecretKey:
    Value: !GetAtt [User1Key, SecretAccessKey]
    Description: AWSSecretAccessKey of User 1
  AccessKey2:
    Value: !Ref 'User2Key'
    Description: AWSAccessKeyId of User 2
  SecretKey2:
    Value: !GetAtt [User2Key, SecretAccessKey]
    Description: AWSSecretAccessKey of User 2
```

I don't know  how to implement this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the methods is to use a IAM policy to achieve the same.

Have a look at the code below. We are creating two policies one for read , one for write. One user is assigned to both read and write policies, other user is assigned only to read.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Resources:
  s3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: Private

  S3ReadPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
    Properties:
      PolicyName: "S3ReadPolicy"
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: s3:GetObject
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${s3Bucket}/*"
          - Action: s3:ListBucket
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${s3Bucket}"
      Users:
        - Ref: User1
        - Ref: User2

  S3WritePolicy:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Policy"
    Properties:
      PolicyName: "S3WritePolicy"
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: s3:PutObject
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::${s3Bucket}/*"
      Users:
        - Ref: User2        

  User1:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User

  User2:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User

  User1Key:
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      UserName: !Ref "User1"

  User2Key:
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      UserName: !Ref "User2"
Outputs:
  AccessKey:
    Value: !Ref "User1Key"
    Description: AWSAccessKeyId of User 1
  SecretKey:
    Value: !GetAtt [User1Key, SecretAccessKey]
    Description: AWSSecretAccessKey of User 1
  AccessKey2:
    Value: !Ref "User2Key"
    Description: AWSAccessKeyId of User 2
  SecretKey2:
    Value: !GetAtt [User2Key, SecretAccessKey]
    Description: AWSSecretAccessKey of User 2
```

hope this helps

Comment: modified the answer to use IAM policy instead of bucket policy

Comment: Corrected the answer to say IAM policy instead of BucketPolicy